# Git status doesn't show changes after moving repo to a new git account

Tags: git, github

I recently moved my Git repository from  one git account to another.
I have 3 servers sync to this git and i'm also connected locally on my computer.

I did a test commit for testing purpose and when i did git pull on the servers i had a message that the repository was moved.

Searched over the net and found that i need to change my git config file and update it with the new URL of the repository.

After changing the config file  i did another commit and i am able to do git pull but the git status before does not show any updates.

How can i make those servers synced with recent updates  so when i do git status it shows the recent changes before i am pulling them?

Appreciate any help on this matter!

Comment: Did you do git pull on your server after pushing the changes from your local?

Comment: Yes  as mentioned the pull works but the status before doesn't show any updates :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After changing the config file i did another commit and i am able to do git pull but the git status before does not show any updates.

`git status` is *never* aware of changes on a remote until you `fetch` from the remote; that is a fundamental fact about the distributed VCS model git uses.

You could build some kind of custom infrastructure, I guess, using the origin repo's "post-receive" hook to let the servers know that there are new changes available for fetch.  Since you seem to have expected the servers to be "aware" of remote changes, I wonder if your old origin repo had something like that set up?

But for "out of the box" git:

- Repo A pushes to origin; Repo B is unaware and `git status` reports nothing
- If Repo B runs `git fetch`, then the changes become visible as the updates are copied into Repo B. `git status` reports that the local branch is ahead/behind origin by X commits.
- If Repo B runs `git pull`, then the changes are fetched (if a separate `git fetch` hadn't already done that) and then merged into the local branch.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation!
I know someone set it up in the old account so when you did a git status on the linux servers  you would see the changes in the repo before pulling that's why i thought it should be like this.

Could you refer me to docs on how to set it up ?

Comment: Well, I just noticed you've tagged your question as `github`, so I assume that's where your origin is hosted? (For future reference, that's important enough that it would help if you call it out in the question. Similar names notwithstanding, github is not git...) I know very little about them (if/to what degree they expose hook functionality; whether they have alternative methods of setting up notifications; ...).  It also complicates matters that ideally you'd want to know how it was done before, so you only have to re-do the github side (and tie into the existing setup on your servers...)

Comment: Basic info on git hooks can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks  But again I doubt that's directly useful for a github-hosted repo.  You could start with github docs about notifications I guess...?

Comment: Yes its hosted on github,  thank you for your time and answer , will read some docs ;]